# System.FormatException: The specified e-mail address is currently not supported

Tags: asp.net, system.net.mail

I receive this error when my code executes from my Windows 2003 server, however from my Windows 7 dev machine the mail process works flawlessly every time. Project is configured for 2.0 framework. Is there a missing component that is needed on the server??

Error Detail.

```
[FormatException: The specified e-mail address is currently not supported.]
   System.Net.Mime.MailBnfHelper.ReadMailAddress(String data, Int32& offset, String& displayName) +1138987
   System.Net.Mail.MailAddress.ParseValue(String address) +240
   System.Net.Mail.MailAddress..ctor(String address, String displayName, Encoding displayNameEncoding) +85
   System.Net.Mail.MailAddress..ctor(String address) +8
   BizHelp.WebForm1.btnSendEmail_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +117
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
```

Web.Config details (this is non-standard format for GoDaddy, but I must run my code on local network, hence I cannot use their relay server - and this works on my Windows 7 box)

```
<mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network host="smtpout.secureserver.net" defaultCredentials="false"
                 userName="xxxxx@sendtome.us" password="xxxxx"  enableSsl="false" port="80"/>
      </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

VB Code:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Dim mm As New MailMessage(lblEmail.Text, "2manybooks@sentome.us")
mm.Subject = "Welcome to xxxx"
mm.IsBodyHtml = True

mm.Body = lblMail.Text.ToString
Dim smtp As New SmtpClient
smtp.Send(mm)
```

Note: lblEmail.text is a field containing a standard email address; that field is loaded from a database.

Any thoughts or suggestions? Thanks!!

Comment: It looks as if the code is crashing on one particular address.  Does it fail on every address or just one?

Comment: I've tried changing the From address - stills fails. Then I tried changing the To address - stills fails.

Comment: Note: the smtp.Send(mm) code is inside a TryCatch loop, but when the page fails, it fails without executing the Catch portion.

Comment: The stack trace you posted doesn't match the code sample you provided.  The stack trace says you're instantiating the class `MailAddress`.  The code has you instantiating `MailMessage`.  Are you sure the error is occurring where you think it is?

Comment: I've been trying various alternatives, here's my original code:        Dim ToAddress As New MailAddress(lblEmail.Text.ToString)
        Dim FromAddress As New MailAddress("2manybooks@sendtome.us")
        Dim mm As New MailMessage(FromAddress, ToAddress)
        
        mm.Subject = "Welcome to xxx"
        mm.IsBodyHtml = True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely thing to be happening is that one or more of the values for your `ToAddress` is just not a valid email address.  I'm thinking it's the `ToAddress` because your `FromAddress` is hard-coded and looks valid.

Try putting a `Debug.WriteLine("\"" + lblEmail.Text + "\"")` statement right before you attempt to create the `ToAddress`.  (The quotation marks are there in case the value is empty.)  After the crash, inspect the Output window, Debug pane.  Is there anything weird there?  Anything that doesn't look like a valid address?

Comment: The error is with the ToAddress. I moved my project over to an XP box running VS2008 - it encountered the same error. And since I was debugging, it shows the specific line of code - the ToAddress. Now I can do some troubleshooting. I'll post what I discover. Thanks

Comment: I found the problem. When I pulled the ToAddress from the database, to improve Readability on the form, I inserted 'Email: ' prior to the actual address. Then I tried to send to that string - wrong. So I added code to strip out the 'Email: ' and now life is wonderful. Thanks!